# python: key combinations such óíúéáöïò with pyhook

Tags: python, keylogger, pyhook

I'm learning about pyhook as keylogger and coding some examples.
I dont know how to log key sequences like óíúö because the result thats something like this -> ´´i´´o

anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

thx you.

Answer (score 0):

I have an example on my site that allows you to see a lot of the information that pyHook provides.  http://fadedbluesky.com/2011/using-pyhook-to-block-windows-key/

Perhaps it can help you find the ScanCode for the key you want.